# Avelut for today

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus

A question on avelut.

One whom is in avelut for a close family.

Are they allowed to travel and eat out after 30days though it’s still within the Year

Comment: "for a close family" Is this specifically not for a parent?

Comment: On a practical level, there are enough variables that one should ask a rabbi for their particularr situation.

Comment: @double AA  Its towards avelut for a parent